# Proof that 0.1011011101111... is irrational

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I know that any rational number has a repeating decimal and therefore the number 0.1011011101111... cannot be rational, however, I don't know the proof of that claim--and besides, I'm curious if there is some particularly easy proof in the case of this particularly simple-looking number.  But nothing comes to mind.  I've thought about doing slightly familiar tricks like multiplying by 10 and subtracting something but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

[Edit:  One thought that occurs to me is that this number looks in some sense self-similar.  I wonder if we can split it into self-similar pieces...]

[Further thought: If this number were in binary it might be easier to make a proof and then generalize it to other radixes.]

Comment: You proved it when you said "I know that any rational number has a repeating decimal and therefore the number 0.1011011101111... cannot be rational"

Comment: You are saying you do not know the proof of the fact that rational numbers must have repeating decimals? Is that the question, or are you looking for alternate proofs?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yeah, I'm hoping for an alternate proof, if there's one that's simpler than the proof that all rational numbers have repeating decimals.

Comment: @Addem Proving that all rational numbers must have repeating decimals is very simple and I doubt you're going to get any simpler.

Comment: do you want to know how to prove that the number you are quoting is not periodic(eventually)?

Comment: It's a non-repeating decimal, so it is irrational. It doesn't get much simpler than this...

Comment: @suomynonA the complication comes from proving that non-repeating decimals are irrational...

Comment: Still, there is no easier way.